# TCP server: will payload delivery happen in pieces?

Tags: tcp, dart

I am writing a TCP server app in Dart. When doing similar things in other languages, I've noticed that even if I send a byte buffer of size X, my onData() receive function will probably be called multiple times with smaller buffers that add up to X. If I'm not mistaken, this happens because of Flow Control. So usually my payload's header contains the payload size, and I use that to wait until I've read the full payload before processing it.

Do I have to handle this manually in Dart too? So far, I have not had issues and I've received the entire payload in a single call to onData(), but I'd rather ask.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have issues either, but you could start processing the data while the response is not yet fully received.
If the response is huge, all data needs to be buffered. This way you aren't able to receive data that is bigger than your available RAM. For example downloading a movie wouldn't be possible this way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. While I'm not sure the exact size of the data transferred to a request, there may be times when you have to completely drain the stream before accessing the data being sent via a POST or other method. (For the body of the http request). See the [Creating a server](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#creating-a-server) section of the Dart Tutorial. In particular you can see how the stream is drained under [Handling POST requests](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/forms/#handling-post-requests). Normally rather than writing back the pieces as the example shows, they are added directly to a buffer as follows:

```dart
var buff = [];
req.listen(buff.addAll, 
  onDone: () { 
    print('Received: ${String.fromCharCodes(buff)}'); 
});
```

See more information on [HttpRequest class documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/dart_io/HttpRequest).

As an alternative, you can use the [http_server package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http_server) which will automatically drain the stream for you and handle the data load properly depending on the headers which are passed with the request. It does this by applying a stream transformer to the incoming HttpRequests stream to convert them to HttpRequestBody. See below for an example. For more details see the [HttpBodyHandler API](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/http_server/http_server.HttpBodyHandler).

```dart
HttpServer.bind(...).then((server) {
  server.transform(new HttpBodyHandler())
    .listen((HttpRequestBody body) {
       // each request is now an HttpRequestBody 
       // which has already drained the stream
       print(body.type);
       print(body.body);
       body.request.response..statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
         ..writeln('Got it!')
         ..close();
    });
 });
```